# Using operator<< with boost iostreams compression filters

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use the boost iostreams compression filters to write to a file using the stream insertion operator (<<). The name "filtering_ostreambuf" suggests that this should behave as a stream but operator<< is not defined for this class. Here's some code that obviously doesn't compile.

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/lzma.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int main() {

  io::filtering_ostreambuf out;
  io::file_sink ofs("output.xz");
  out.push(ofs);
  out.push(io::lzma_compressor());

  for (int i=0; i<16; ++i) {
    out << i << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I've tried using a stringstream as a 'source' and using the boost iostreams copy() with it as per the example for the gzip decompression. But (1) it doesn't work and (2) even if it did, that seems to be overly verbose to me and doesn't sound like it would be very efficient.

Is there a way to use boost iostreams so that I can just write to a filter chain normally as if it was a stream ? I want to use << not write().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you use `ostreambuf` it's just a stream buffer. `stream` classes derive from `std::basic_ostream` and support [formatted io "stream" operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) (they are actually bit-shift operators).

So this should work:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/lzma.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int main() {

  io::filtering_ostream out;
  io::file_sink ofs("output.xz");
  out.push(io::lzma_compressor());
  out.push(ofs);

  for (int i=0; i<16; ++i) {
    out << i << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

At [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2kFcnnQYwp95uO2X) it fails at linking which is understandable, but compilation itself passes.

Comment: Yes that does work and compiles an links for me with g++ -o compress compress.cpp -std=c++11 -lboost_iostreams -llzma.

Comment: Good to know. Btw, I've changed order in `out` chain, as your edit suggested. Looking at [usage examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/filter_usage.html) it seems that file sink should indeed be last. Sorry for this mistake but I wasn't able to test it in runtime. Cheers.